# error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0 while trying to replace to backslah

Tags: python, backslash

I need to replace single backslash in my string.
I'm trying to perform '\' but it gives with me double backslash.
When i'm performing '\' it throw error  bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0

```
string = 'abrakadabra'
string.replace('a','\\')
#or
re.sub('a','\\','abrakadabra')

In [47]: string.replace('a','\'')
Out[47]: "'br'k'd'br'"

In [48]: string.replace('a','\')
 File "<ipython-input-48-e884682860ae>", line 1
string.replace('a','\')
                       ^
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
In [49]: string.replace('a','\\')
Out[49]: '\\br\\k\\d\\br\\'

In [50]:
```

expecting for result:
\br\k\d\br\

Comment: Run `print(string.replace('a','\\'))` to see there are no double backslashes.

Answer (score 13):

You should use `'\\\\'`, then you will pass `'\\'` to re, which is just one escaped backslash.

```
print(re.sub('a','\\\\','abrakadabra'))
# \br\k\d\br\
```

Comment: Or explicitly tell python it's actually raw backslashes `r'\\'`